# Mysql order by two columns, primary, and secondary

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table that I want to select data by my date (`end`) in descending order and then reorder by `key`.

```
SELECT * FROM `payschedule`
WHERE `end` <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY `end` DESC,
`key` ASC
LIMIT 3
```

For example if I have:

```
key   end
1     2014...
2     2015...
3     2016...
4     2017...
5     2018... // current date
```

My query should return:

```
3    2016
4    2017
5    2018
```

Comment: Don't use reserved words as table/column identifiers. It will drive you (and/or us) mad.

Comment: @nic can you explain it more

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka See EoinS's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT * from 
(
SELECT * FROM `payschedule`
WHERE `end` <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY `end` DESC
LIMIT 3
) t
order by `key` ASC
```

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/JNSZWK86068)